# How to find the number of terms in the expansion of $(a+b+c)^2$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, binomial-coefficients

How to find the number of terms in the expansion of $(a+b+c)^2$?

Can anyone help me in finding its formula with proof?

Comment: Are $ab$ and $ba$ different terms or are you counting them after simplification to $2ab$ assuming commutativity?

Comment: You can determine that by finding the product $(a + b + c)(a + b + c)$.  Alternatively, each term is of the form $a^xb^yc^z$, where $x + y + z = 2$, so you could also find the answer by finding the number of solutions of the equation $x + y + z = 2$ in the nonnegative integers, which is a [combinations with repetition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination#Number_of_combinations_with_repetition) problem.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem for the general formula with proof

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We basically have to divide the power of $2$ amongst the $ a , b, c$. Let the powers be $ x, y , z $.

$ x+y+z = 2$ where x , y,z are integers.

So the answer is $6$.

Using the formula  $C_{ r-1}^{n+r-1}$